# ngModel bind won't work on multiple checkboxes

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I have data that looks like this

```
[{value: 6, name: "delete-wews", checked: false}
{value: 5, name: "update-user", checked: false}
{value: 4, name: "search-user", checked: true}
{value: 3, name: "list-user", checked: false}
{value: 2, name: "find-user", checked: false}
{value: 1, name: "create-user", checked: true}]
```

Now in my template it looks this, but when it displays on the browser it checks all the checkbox even if its value is false. It should check if the "checked" key is true otherwise it should go false.

```
<div class="checkbox" *ngFor="let permission of permissions">
      <label>
         <input type="checkbox"
            name="permissions"
            [(ngModel)]="permission.checked"
            value="{{permission.id}}">
            {{permission.name}}
     </label>
</div>
```

and my controller code is this
https://gist.github.com/eaponiente/cc108bfafb2789229e917283e0b8db09

Comment: Do you have id key in the real 'permissions' arrays? You are setting value to the non existing key

Comment: Don't put answers in questions. Put answers in answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its because you're using ngFor to iterate over that array and you're setting the same name attribute for every item. They need to each be unique to hold different values. Try this, which will make the names permissions0, permissions1, permissions2, etc.

```
<div class="checkbox" *ngFor="let permission of permissions; let i = index">
  <label>
     <input type="checkbox"
        [name]="'permissions'+i"
        [(ngModel)]="permission.checked"
        value="{{permission.id}}">
        {{permission.name}}
 </label>
```

Comment: One common mistake is that radio inputs all need the same name but not checkboxes.

Comment: Also if you are trying to bing to the particular object for the checkbox: 
permission[i].checked

Comment: one last thing... always use [value]="permission.id" this will retain the type of the string, int, or boolean, etc.

Comment: You shouldn't need to add an index after 'pernission', as the 'let permission of permissions' syntax is declaring 'permission' as a temporary template variable through each iteration of the array. Similar to doing the same thing in ES6 javascript.  for (let item of array) {   console.log(item); }   displays a different item every time, no index needed. But permissions, with the s on the end, is not declared like that, so will be static with each iteration.

Comment: They need the index as a way to make the name of the checkbox unique. Thats all

Comment: the answer seems ok for the first few tries after a while, the json data does not change anymore.